# copy constructor inheritance

Tags: java

I looked at this link, but didn't really understand what was meant by the [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635078/java-copy-constructor-and-inheritance)

Anyways onto my question, so I have a class which inherits two attributes from another class,
the class it inherits from has set/get methods and a copy constructor.

I want to implement a copy constructor into the inheriting class (ignore comments in code)

```
public class Instructor extends Person{
    //officeNumber represents the office number where instructors can be found
    private String officeNumber;

    //constructor allows user to define first and last name and office number in demo
    public Instructor(String fName, String lName, String officeNumber) {
        super(fName, lName);
        this.officeNumber=officeNumber;
    }
}
```

I want to put the copy constructor here and so far all I can do is this, but I can't just pass in an object into another constructor in a demo class, I have to include the full name

```
public Instructor(String fName, String lName,Instructor object2) {
    super(fName,lName);
    officeNumber=object2.officeNumber;
}
//get method for field
public String getOfficeNumber() {
    return officeNumber;
}
}
```

Here is the class it inherits from if that's any help

```
public class Person {
    //firstName represents the first name of a person
    private String firstName;
    //lastName represents the last name of a person
    private String lastName;

    //constructor allows programmer to define first and last name of object in demo
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //copy constructor
    public Person(Person object2) {
        firstName = object2.firstName;
        lastName = object2.lastName;
    }

    //get methods for fields
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would appear you don't understand variable scope, objects, inheritance, or how to use methods. Your base class gives you getters for both `firstName` and `lastName`. I would highly suggest starting with a good beginner's book on Java or the Oracle Java tutorials.

Comment: If anything is unclear, just send me a comment and I'll try to fix.

Comment: Yes I know, I can't say fName=object2.fName because they're not from the same method, but previously I did not use inheritance and had a copy constructor for this class and would like to reinstate that while keeping the whole inheritance thing going

Comment: Well, no one has yet to answer my question or even explain what I'm doing wrong. So besides editing the thanks out of my original post and adding a few spaces, no one has done anything constructive.

Comment: People should understand that not every question on this site is going to be about high level programming, some of us are rudimentary programmers who don't know where to find answers.

Comment: @gucci No, _you_ should understand that this site is not about teaching you programming basics - there's enough tutorials and other resources for this, use them. The answer in your case is to simply use the `get` methods for first and last name, like Brian mentioned. You failed to realize his comment was constructive because your knowledge of Java and OOP basics is lacking.

Comment: @l4mpi, I don't need someone coming onto my questions calling me an idiot.  Karthikeyan gave me the answer I needed, I'm tired of all of you karma whoring, this isn't reddit. If you ask someone a question and they say go read a book, how is that answer useful? Do I have time to read a book? Do you not think I've already been searching for the answer? Also get methods don't work I tried that fool

Comment: @gucci I didn't call you an idiot; but I'm starting to question your reading comprehension. And calling me a fool because you don't understand how to use methods just displays your ignorance. While you might not have the time to read a book, there are plenty of tutorials that take way less time to read. Also, the response you get has nothing to do with "karma whoring", nobody gets reputation for downvoting/flagging/closevoting. It's just that the community agrees that your question is bad - and bad questions get downvoted, flagged and closevoted in an effort to keep this site's standards high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please elaborate your question.

You could have a copy constructor in Instructor like this,

This code is only for understanding.

```
public class Instructor extends Person {
    public String getIname() {
        return iname;
    }

    public void setIname(String iname) {
        this.iname = iname;
    }

    private String iname;

    public Instructor(Person p, String myinstructor) {
        super(p);
        this.iname = myinstructor;
    }

    public Instructor(Instructor clone) {
        super(clone);
        this.iname = clone.iname;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the above. Why is it down voted?